# Unity3d Реклама Admob

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, admob, встроенная-реклама

Помогите решить проблему,пробую вставить рекламу в свою игру,межстраничная реклама ,которая должна "всплыть" после смерти игрока,но когда персонаж умирает,выбивает с игры,без кода адмбоа всё работает и игра не вылетает ,вылетает только с рекламой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы приведёте здесь код ошибки, помочь вам будет проще)

Comment: Минус вопросу за вставку кода картинкой.